# spring Bean creation exception Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hello all i am new to Spring please solve my problem i am getting bean creation exception here is my code(i created these in dynamic web project) i am trying to do a simple Springmvc project.

file name:  login.Jsp

```
<form action="login.do" method="post">
username<input type="text" name="username"/>
password<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

file name : web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>loginapp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>loginapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

file name:loginapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
        <bean id="id1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
          <property name="mappings">
             <props>
                 <prop key="login.do">id2</prop>

        </props>
        </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="id2" class="logincontroller"/>
</beans>
```

file name : logincontroller.java

```
package springmvc;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class logincontroller implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        loginaction action = new loginaction();
        String result = action.verifyuser(username,password);
        if(result.equals("success"))
        return new ModelAndView("success.jsp");
        else
            return new ModelAndView("failure.jsp");


    }

}
```

filename : success.jsp

```
<% out.println("login success");%>
```

file name: failure.jsp

```
<% out.println("failed");%>
```

after i run login.jsp and typing username as "admin" password as "admin" i am getting this error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet loginapp threw exception


type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet loginapp threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet loginapp threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'id1' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/loginapp-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [logincontroller] for bean with name 'id2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/loginapp-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logincontroller
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [logincontroller] for bean with name 'id2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/loginapp-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logincontroller
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [logincontroller] for bean with name 'id2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/loginapp-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logincontroller
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:422)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.isSingleton(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:286)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:104)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logincontroller
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:422)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.isSingleton(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:286)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:104)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Pivotal tc Runtime 3.2.2.RELEASE/8.5.6.B.RELEASE logs.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Pivotal tc Runtime 3.2.2.RELEASE/8.5.6.B.RELEASE
```

Here are the jar files i copied in lib folder :

```
commons-logging-1.2.jar
spring-aop-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aop-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-beans-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-build-src-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-core-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-expression-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-expression-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jms-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jms-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-orm-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-orm-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-test-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-test-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-tx-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-tx-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
```

Comment: your exception states `nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: logincontroller` and your class is `springmvc.logincontroller`, you have to explicitly add the packagename of your class! fix this in your bean definition and you're good

Comment: @vinod as a good practice please use camel case for class names in java

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion satya . thank you japu my problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="id2" class="logincontroller"/>
```

this line is causing this issue.

You need to mention fully qualified class name in class attribute. something like this.

```
 <bean id="id2" class="X.logincontroller"/>
```

where X is your fully qualified package name.